# List view inside navigation drawer is not scrolling when root element is scrollview in landscape mode

Tags: android, scrollview

here is my XML page

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" >

        <!--
         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        -->

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/light_grey"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
        android:background="#0077BA"
        android:isScrollContainer="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="4dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:text="Find a Product"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spn_products"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:background="@drawable/login_edit_text" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_ed_go"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/go_btn"
                        android:onClick="btn_spnProduct_go"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spn_area"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:background="@drawable/login_edit_text" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_spnarea_go"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/go_btn"
                        android:onClick="btn_spnarea_go"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spn_industry"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:background="@drawable/login_edit_text" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_spnindustry_go"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/go_btn"
                        android:onClick="btn_spnIndustry_go"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i am newb to android please let me know where i am  doing mistake i googled it some answers still giving me drawer-layout must be measured exactly error.Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very complex layout design...

Comment: can you let me know how to do this in short way i am facing problem with it from 3 days i cant solve this thing

Comment: You have to rearrange your menu.. Your navigation drawer should be simple one. You can move some of menus to somewhere else.. This is my suggestion only.

Comment: You should not put `ListView` into `ScrollView`, the touch events and scroll gestures are consumed by the `ScrollView` and the `ListView` won't work properly.

Comment: do not put `ListView` with `ScrollView`, I agree with @Lamorak

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

If you want scroll navigation drawer in landscape in xml you set: